Laravel ORM whereHas() and orWhere() filter not working
Currently I'm making a function that displays news
public function getAllNews($listBranches, $listGrade, $userId, $limit, $search, $language, $excludeId = null, $tagIds = null, $listBrandCode): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $models = $this->model->with([
            'newsBrands', 'newsGrades', 'newsBranches',
            'userNewsLikeShare' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userId);
            },
        ])->whereIn('status', [NewsStatus::POSTED->value, NewsStatus::OUTSTANDING->value])
        ->where('date_post', '<=', now());

        $brandCode = $search['brand_code'] ?? BrandEnum::TDS->value;
 
        if (count($listBranches) > 0) {
            $models->whereHas('newsBrands', function ($query) use ($listBranches, $brandCode, $listBrandCode) {
                $query->where('abbreviation_name', $brandCode);
                if (!empty($listBranches) && in_array(strtolower($brandCode), $listBrandCode)) {
                    $query->whereIn('branch_id', array_values($listBranches));
                }
            });
            if (!empty($listBranches)) {
                $models->whereHas('newsBranches', function ($query) use ($listBranches) {
                    $query->whereIn('branch_id', $listBranches);
                })->orWhereDoesntHave('newsBranches');
            }
        }

        if (count($models->get()) == 0 || count($listBranches) == 0) {
            $models = $this->model->with([
                'newsBranches', 'newsGrades',
                'userNewsLikeShare' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
                },
            ])->where('status', NewsStatus::POSTED->value);
            $models = $models->whereHas('newsBrands', function ($query) use ($brandCode) {
                $query->where('abbreviation_name', $brandCode);
            });
            $models = $models->whereHas('newsTypes', function ($q) {
                $q->where('news_types_id', NewTypeEvents::EVENTS->value);
            });
        }

        if (!empty($search['search'])) {
            $text_search = $search['search'];
            $models->where(function ($q) use ($text_search, $language) {
                $q->whereRaw("LOWER(json_extract(title, '$.$language')) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci like (?)", '%' . strtolower($text_search) . '%')
                    ->orWhereRaw("LOWER(json_extract(description, '$.$language')) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci like (?)", '%' . strtolower($text_search) . '%');
            });
        }
        $models = $models->select([
            "id", "image", "title", "description", "likes", "views", "date_post", "is_pin",
            "link_share", "is_outstanding", "created_at", "updated_at", "status",
        ])->when($excludeId, function ($q) use ($excludeId) {
            $q->whereNot('id', $excludeId);
        })->when($tagIds, function ($q) use ($tagIds) {
            $q->whereHas('newsTags', function ($subQ) use ($tagIds) {
                $subQ->whereIn('tags_id', $tagIds);
            });
        })
        ->when(count($listGrade) > 0, function ($subQ) use ($listGrade) {
            $subQ->where(function ($subQ) use ($listGrade) {
                $subQ->whereDoesntHave('newsGrades')->orWhereHas('newsGrades', function ($subQ) use ($listGrade) {
                    $subQ->whereIn('grade_id', $listGrade);
                });
            });
        })->whereHas('newsBrands', function ($query) use ($brandCode) {
            $query->where('abbreviation_name', $brandCode);
        });
        
        $orderBy = !empty($search['order_by']) ? $search['order_by'] : ['updated_at'];
        $sortedBy = !empty($search['sort_by']) ? $search['sort_by'] : 'desc';
        foreach ($orderBy as $value) {
            $models = $models->orderBy($value, $sortedBy);
        }
        $models->orderBy('status', 'desc');
        Log::channel('deferment_application')->info(
            $models->toSql().' - grade: '. implode(',', $listGrade)
            .' - branchID: '. implode(',', $listBranches)
        );

        $categoryNews = $search['category_news'] ?? [];
        if (count($categoryNews)) {
            $models->where(function ($query) use ($categoryNews) {
                foreach ($categoryNews as $category) {
                    switch ($category) {
                        case NewsCategories::School->value:
                            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->whereHas('newsBranches')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsStudyPrograms')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsSchoolShips')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsGrades')
                                    ->whereHas('newsTypes', function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('name->en', '!=', 'Events');
                                    });
                            });

                            break;
                        case NewsCategories::GradeCategory->value:
                            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->whereHas('newsGrades')
                                    ->whereHas('newsTypes', function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('name->en', '!=', 'Events');
                                    });
                            });

                            break;
                        case NewsCategories::Event->value:
                            $query->orWhereHas('newsTypes', function ($query) {
                                $query->where('name->en', 'Events');
                            });

                            break;
                        case NewsCategories::SubjectCombinationCategory->value:
                            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->whereHas('newsSchoolShips')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsGrades')
                                    ->whereHas('newsTypes', function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('name->en', '!=', 'Events');
                                    });
                            });

                            break;
                        case NewsCategories::StudyProgram->value:
                            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->whereHas('newsStudyPrograms')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsSchoolShips')
                                    ->whereDoesntHave('newsGrades')
                                    ->whereHas('newsTypes', function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('name->en', '!=', 'Events');
                                    });
                            });

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return $models->paginate($limit);
    }


But when filtering by $categoryNews, it still always returns the news that I filtered out with whereDoesntHave()
Here is my relationship:
    public function newsStudyPrograms(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProgramBase::class, 'news_config_study_program', 'news_id', 'study_program_id');
    }

    public function newsGrades(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(GradeBase::class, 'news_config_grade', 'news_id', 'grade_id');
    }

    public function newsSchoolShips(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SchoolShipBase::class, 'news_config_school_ship', 'news_id', 'school_ship_id');
    }

    public function newsTypes(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(NewsTypesBase::class, 'news_has_news_types', 'news_id', 'news_types_id');
    }

Does anyone have any solution?
My logic is that when filtering any news, I will only display that exact type of news. I can filter many categories at the same time. For example, if I filter NewsCategories::School and NewsCategories::GradeCategory, I will only display exactly the news of this two categories.

Please try to share only the code snippet related to what you are trying to achieve so it's easier to help you.
